# Retrieving Data From SQL Server in Grid View

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to connect my Android Application to SQL Server database to check login credentials and then loading that data in `GridView`.

But now i don't know how to work with calling or executing the SQL-Server stored procedures in android application. Can you please help me in executing Stored Procedures from Android Application?

Comment: I'm looking for someone to give the right doc.

Comment: That I understood... you're only not looking at the right place as SO is not for this kind of questions. What you need would be either a common user forum or even a simple search engine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use stored procedure in SQLite, **you can't**. SQLite does not support stored procedures. Neither in Android, nor in other environments.

If you want to call external SQL-server, you can use JDBC.

Comment: but i need a documentation or somthing like that.

Comment: @estemEvent about connection with SQL-server?